# wireless connection asking password for every connection fail

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

My system knows the password for a wireless ssid, and it is connected too. but whenever the wireless connection is disconnected it should always try connect to it, but after three or 4 attempts it is assuming like "the wifi password is not correct" so it is again asking like this.
[image]

i don't want to get this prompt, because i have to hit enter to connect again but i havent keyboard and mouse so i am operating my pc with remote system so if this type of prompts appear then it will not connect to wifi again.

the wifi connection should not stop for trying the wifi but it should not ask the password again how to automate this?